# Garbage collection in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, garbage-collection

I just started with ECMAScript 2015 within Meteor.  Was wondering about garbage collection of instantiated Classes once I route to a different page (iron router).  Is garbage collection taken care of, or must I do it manually?  I'm concerned that every time I revisit a chunk of code associated with a given page that instantiates a class, that prior class instances will pile up.

Comment: Yes, JavaScript is a garbage-collected language. This did not change with ES6 btw.

Comment: Could you please give a sample code to illustrate the way you manage your objects in your router?

Comment: Yes, Javascript is garbage-collected.  But it's up to me to remove references to the class instances to allow gc to work.  Wondering if Meteor does anything special with gc, or does it just allow javascript to do its thing?